# Login htpasswd via CURL and keep the session in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, session-cookies, .htpasswd

I have several folders (one for each client) and I save into them images that only can be accesed by himselfs.

The folders are protected via htpasswd and I'm trying to login via cUrl after the user normal login and keep this session alive and allow the users to navigate and access only his folder images.

In my Authentification controller I'm doing this:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'routeToOneFileInHisFolder');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);    
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I tried also setting a curl_setopt for COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE with no different result. I don't know if I'm having the wrong approach or if I'm missing some code.

Comment: I think you will have to do that from the client / javascript: Right now you are trying to authenticate the server and not the user's browser. Personally I would serve the directories and files from php so that it does not matter where they are stored; if access is granted in the database, you can show them.

Comment: Thanks jeroen. The problem is that we have millions of files and our plattaform needs to serve the file as fast as we can because our bussiness core. We use Symfony and we tried send to a controller, do some validations and then serve the image but it's impossible for us loose that time

Comment: Then you should try to make an ajax request to the directory when the user logs in.

Comment: I tried but seems not working. The ajax return the image correctly if I set the credentials but if I navigate to the image the browser ask me again for username and password. Thanks anyway, nice try (I thought it was going to work...)

Comment: Strange... And if you try to get the whole directory instead of a specific file?

Comment: nah, the problem in this case is Symfony returns me "Route not found" (only if I access to real file the route controller not been launched). Anyway I'm going to continue in this way (with ajax) because I think I'm missing something. It's impossible that there are no way to do this because it have all logic

Comment: You should post the solution when you find it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve this. Although it is not a very secure method, it is a good solution for my problem.

Thanks to Aberel I started to investigate around cookies and the http auth. After that I'm able to set a cookie with PHP (or with JS, there are no differences) and check it with the .htaccess in each folder. The .htaccess looks like this:

```
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
AuthName "Forbidden"
AuthType Basic
SetEnvIfNoCase Cookie COOKIENAME = randomHash $ PASS = 1

Require valid-user

#Allow valid-user
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env = PASS
Satisfy any
```

The COOKIENAME can be anything and the randomHash you identify each user.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your welcome! I'm interested to know the final solution, can you post the code where you set that cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_SESSION, i.e....

```
//put this in the top of your php
session_start();

//then store the user and password in the session...
$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
$_SESSION['password'] = 'password';

// replace in your code anywhere the $username and $password variables 
// with the new $_SESSION['username'] and $_SESSION['password']
```

Comment: That is a very bad idea, you should not store a plain-text password in the session. And how would it help the OP?

Comment: That not work. Further, I already have a session (with Symfony) and it's possible that this one overwrites something in it (but I'm not sure of that)

Comment: jimixjay : I you already have a session, maybe you can try to reuse it. The phpsession is who creates the sessoin cookie.

Comment: jeroen: I know is not a good idea to store a password. i just followed the code in the question, replaced the harcoded variable. 
Maybe... curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$_SESSION['username']}:{$_SESSION['password']}");   or something...

In some cases, when you need to keep session with another server, or api, or whatever external app, you don't have another option. Or trying to keep the other-app-session alive with a cookie.

Comment: Hi Aberel. This feature is on the same project and same server. I tried to print the two session variables that you mentioned after login the image url but they are returning NULL. I also tried with $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and also they are NULL. You mentioned that "the phpsession is who creates the session cookie" but I'm trying to pass the auth with apache. The problem is set this type of auth with PHp and keep it alive

Comment: Hi jimixjay, now I understand your problem. In your first main question, it's not clear if you get succesful authentication using CURL. In other words, I din't have clear if your problem is with CURL AUTH, or the problem is to KEEP IT ALIVE.  Now I think that is the second one, is it?

Comment: Exactly. However, with CURL I'm able to login successfully also. The problem is keep it alive when the user navigates in the page

Comment: So, what happens... any time the user access a new page (or reloads) the auth box prompts again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164356/discussion-between-jimixjay-and-aberel).